# lerna add on unpublished packages resulting in 404

Tags: lerna

I have just started a fresh project with `lerna@3.11.1`. When I try to run the following:

```
lerna add @ellisio/lerna-travis-b --scope=@ellisio/lerna-travis-a
```

I get the following output:

```
info cli using local version of lerna
lerna notice cli v3.11.1
lerna info filter [ '@ellisio/lerna-travis-a' ]
lerna info Adding @ellisio/lerna-travis-b in 1 package
lerna notice filter including "@ellisio/lerna-travis-a"
lerna info filter [ '@ellisio/lerna-travis-a' ]
lerna WARN bootstrap Installing local packages that do not match filters from registry
lerna info Bootstrapping 1 package
lerna info Installing external dependencies
lerna ERR! npm install --no-save exited 1 in '@ellisio/lerna-travis-a'
lerna ERR! npm install --no-save stderr:
npm ERR! code E404
npm ERR! 404 Not Found: @ellisio/lerna-travis-b@^0.0.0
```

Neither of these packages are published yet. I have tried changing the version manually in both package's `package.json` to `0.0.1` but the same output occurs; just with `^0.0.1` as the version.

I was under the assumption that `lerna add` would add local packages via this method, published or unpublished.

If I manually add `"@ellisio/lerna-travis-b": "0.0.0"` to travis-a's package.json, then run `npm i && npx lerna bootstrap --hoist` everything runs fine.

The tree of the project:

```
.
├── lerna.json
├── package-lock.json
├── package.json
└── packages
    ├── lerna-travis-a
    │   ├── package.json
    └── lerna-travis-b
        ├── package.json
```

`packages/lerna-travis-a/package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "@ellisio/lerna-travis-a",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "description": "Package A",
}
```

`packages/lerna-travis-b/package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "@ellisio/lerna-travis-b",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "description": "Package B",
}
```

`lerna.json`:

```
{
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "packages": [
    "packages/*"
  ]
}
```